# Best way to get neighboring pixels on image

Tags: c, image, image-processing

I'm working on a image filter. On the blur filter i need to get data of the neighbor pixels of one pixel to update it's RGB values. To do so I'm using something like:

```
            RGBTRIPLE *neighbors;
            int array_size;
            if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                array_size = 4;
                neighbors = malloc(array_size * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
                neighbors[0] = image[i][j];
                neighbors[1] = image[i][j + 1];
                neighbors[2] = image[i + 1][j];
                neighbors[3] = image[i][j + 1];
            } else if (i == height - 1 && j == 0) {
                array_size = 4;
                neighbors = malloc(array_size * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
                neighbors[0] = image[i + 1][j];
                neighbors[1] = image[i + 1][j + 1];
                neighbors[2] = image[i][j];
                neighbors[3] = image[i][j + 1];
            }
```

And having an if statement for each case (top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right, up, left, bottom, right and no corner). But this makes the code extremely big and inefficient. Is there a better way to do so?

The RGBTRIPLE is a pixel struct defined as:

```
typedef uint8_t  BYTE;
typedef struct {
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

Comment: You could reduce the overall number of tests by doing the safe, middle portion of the image in a 2-nested loop, then do the middles of each edge in its own loop, then do the four corners. You will need special cases for images less than 2 pixels wide and/or less than 2 pixels high.

Comment: You are surely not doing a `malloc()` at every pixel location?

Comment: I am doing the `malloc()` just for this temp array, it will be called just once, to store all the possible neighbors, is that a bad idea?

Comment: If this is inside a loop over an image, calling malloc is bad.  A malloc/free usually requires a  few hundred instructions and sometimes much more.  It's almost certainly dominating run time here.  Also almost certainly your logic can be reorganized to use a locally declared array or maybe none at all.

Comment: @IanAbbott is right, but if you turn up the right optimizations, the compiler ought to take care of that for you, leaving your program simpler.  Along the way it will probably use vector instructions and/or other parallelization tricks.

Comment: @Gene got it, so its better to let all the arrays with the same size and have some unused bytes on it than calling those.

Comment: And so the best way to do it would be having all those branches? And of course, removing the malloc/free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of data doesn't matter, you can use loops to count and collect in-range pixels.

```
RGBTRIPLE *neighbors;
int array_size = 0;

/* count in-range pixels */
for (int k = -1; k <= 1; k++) {
    for (int l = -1; l <= 1; l++) {
        if (0 <= i + k && i + k < height && 0 <= j + l && j + l < width) {
            array_size++;
        }
    }
}

/* allocate the array */
neighbors = malloc(array_size * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
if (neighbors == NULL) {
    /* handle error */
}

/* collect pixel values */
int cnt = 0;
for (int k = -1; k <= 1; k++) {
    for (int l = -1; l <= 1; l++) {
        if (0 <= i + k && i + k < height && 0 <= j + l && j + l < width) {
            neighbors[cnt++] = image[i + k][j + l];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be more efficient if the range of `i + k` is tested in the outer loop, before committing to a whole inner loop, and also (more importantly) saving the checks of `i + k` in the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

> And having an if statement for each case (top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right, up, left, bottom, right and no corner). But this makes the code extremely big and inefficient. Is there a better way to do so?

A common technique is to have extra room at the sides so that you can access a default value (to avoid the branches) or a tombstone value of some sort (to simplify the code).

As for slow, you would need to profile to see whether that is true or not. Most branches will be correctly predicted most of the time if the image is big enough.

If it is true that the branches are really slowing you down, then you will have to make the code more complex, e.g. splitting the processing into border/no border cases as @IanAbbott suggests.

Comment: If I add extra room the output image won't the output image change? Because the values of the pixel after the filtering will depend on the value of the pixel on this extra space. I will try the border no border, this way remove both problems

Comment: Yes, of course, your code would need adjustment so that its output is a subset of the entire memory you are using. The extra memory would be there to handle the border case, not as an actual output.